# How to say 'each other'?

Tags: grammaire, pronoms

For example, if I wanted to say 'We showed each other our houses' would you write 'nous nous sommes montrés nos maisons'?

Comment: nous nous sommes montré nos maisons. le COD de montrer est nos maisons, donc pas d'accord. le 2ème nous est un COI.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What were you unsure about?

Answer (score 1):

**Oui**, la phrase est correcte. Cependant le participe passé *montré* ne comporte pas de ***S***

> Nous nous sommes montré nos maisons.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence should be grammaticaly correct, although I would not use it. 
I would rather say something like :
Nous avons montré nos maisons l'un à l'autre. 
The "l'un à l'autre" means that one has shown it to the other but implies that it also happened the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Une reformulation soutenue :

> Chacun de nous a montré sa maison.

« Chacun de nous a montré sa maison », *à l'autre* est sous-entendu, d'ailleurs cela pourrait être *aux autres*, car la phrase reste correcte que l'on soit deux ou mille.